# decode array of objects in vapor

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, decode, vapor

How can i decode the following json-array (which is part of a http-request)

```
[ 
  { "id": 0, "name": "darth maul" }, 
  { "id": 1, "name": "darth sidious" } 
]
```

in swift vapor 3 with the decode function?

vapor code:

```
struct User: Content {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

router.put("user") { request -> Future<HTTPStatus> in
    return try request.content.decode(User.self).map({ (user) -> (HTTPStatus) in
        // process ...
        return .ok
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you mean for the client, the receiving it?

Comment: No, I mean the client (e.g. an iphone) send a http request to the server (implemented with vapor). The server defines the route "user" and must use a decode function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is pretty close already, only a tiny change is needed: instead of decoding a single User, decode an array of them. Note the square brackets in `decode`.

```
router.put("user") { request -> Future<HTTPStatus> in
    return try request.content.decode([User].self).map({ (users) -> (HTTPStatus) in
        // process ...
        return .ok
    })
}
```

Comment: Your answer was useful and the request-decoding works! But when i am starting the vapor service, the following error occurs: DecodingError.typeMismatch: Value of type 'Array<Any>' required for key ''. (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26). Can you help?

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if one item in your array fails to decode then they all fail to decode. If you could first decode them in to an array of some generic type and then iterate and decode one by one you would be able to decode all complete data and discard the broken data.